# ASP .net 3.5 multi file upload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a requirment where the client needs to upload multiple files. The requirement is in such a way that when client selects th browse button a popup similar to windows explorer should come with some check boxe, where the client will be able to select multiple files and once he selects them a and clicks the upload button, the selected files need to be uploaded to the server.I have googled and gone through options of using jQuery/javascript to do the same, but was thinking whether it is possible to build a custom control for this requirement. May I knwo if there will be any limitations for this requirment in ASP .net 3.5?

And all th samples that I have gone through google does not allow user to select multiple files using a kind of windows explorer view(tree view with a check box for files). The examples are in such a way that the user selects one file at a time and then selects other files in a sequence and then uploads all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: http://www.uploadify.com

Comment: I saw uploadify. But aprt from this multifile upload control. I have four form controls which needs to be submitted during the submit action. So my form will have four input controls along with thismultifile control.

Comment: CONINUING FROM MY PREVIOUS COMMENT.... I can use the multifile control to select multiple files but the upload needs to happen only after I hit the main save button. At the server, in the page_load function I expect to see the form control values along with the multifile upload fila data,so that I can store them in the database. Will uploadify satisfy my requirement?